# Emulate a tilted / perspective global projection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system

I am looking to emulate the perspective of the base map used in this image, using ArcMap 10.4.

[image]

Basically an isometric view of all the continents with the view at an angle.  the Southern Hemisphere continents appear larger and the northern hemisphere look smaller.

I can simulate this view in ArcScene, however I find it difficult to get the symbology to work as I need it to.

Comment: Oh, look, no New Zealand.

Comment: I don't think ArcGIS has a projection that would match this. I looked at a few but nothing was really close.

Comment: In this example no NZ but in my map NZ is there